# Uploading a file to S3

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm generating a [Pre-Signed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) `URL` on the server side and uploading a `file` on a client side.

For some reason, I receive a `403 forbidden SignatureDoesNotMatch` error from `AWS` but I can't see where is the error.

Using `postman` to request that `url`, that's what I receive as a `response`:

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/uploads/%20VID_20160916_061949.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJV3UP7LBEKPYMLGA&Expires=1474005709&Signature=7KYWah4K%2FEkpdYQR%2FqYDrvCDPgQ%3D
```

Here bellow I paste my code:

**AngularJS**

```
// My videoData comes as a variable
$http.post(CONFIG.API_URL + '/endpoint1', { filename: videoData[0].name })
  .success(function (resp) {
  // Perform The Push To S3
    $http.put(resp, videoData[0], { headers: {'Content-Type': videoData[0].type} })
      .success(function (resp) {
        //Finally, We're done
        callback(null, 'Upload Done!');
      })
      .error(function (resp) {
        callback("An Error Occurred Attaching Your File");
      });
  })
  .error(function (resp) {
    callback("An Error Occurred Attaching Your File");
});
```

**NodeJS**

```
getSignedUrl: function (filename, callback) {
  if (filename) {
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'my_access_key',
      secretAccessKey: 'my_secret_key',
      region: 'us-west-2' // I've checked the bucket is correct
    });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {Bucket: 'my_bucket', Key: 'uploads/' + filename}, function (err, url) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback(url);
      }
    });
  } else {
    callback('Error');
  }
}
```

**Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1474002303781",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1473001308637",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::my_user:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/uploads"
        }
    ]
}
```

**CORS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>600</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: I assume that the put was successful. However, you are unable to access the url using postman? If that is the case, the pre-signaled url will expire after 15 mins by default. Are you trying to access the URL after 15 mins?

Comment: Postman returns me the response I already pasted as well as angular receive the URL. The problem comes when I try to upload the file. It says that the ‘signature‘ doesn't match.

Comment: `s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', ...` needs the appropriate argument to match the `Content-Type` header the client will be sending.

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks!