# cordova-plugin-file-upload SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524749/uploading-a-file-to-s3) other post of mine, I'm able to upload through `$http.put` without problems, but using [$cordovaFileTransfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) it says that the `SignatureDoesNotMatch`.

Here below I paste my new code:

```
fCordovaPlugins.uploadS3(response, videoData[0].fullPath, videoData[0].type, videoData[0].name, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(response);
});

uploadS3: function (url, videoPath, type, name, callback) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = name;
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";
    options.headers = {
      "Content-Type": type
    };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(videoPath, encodeURI(url), callback, callback, options);
 }
```